# Peculiar problem rendering specific triangles

Tags: directx11

I've encountered a strange problem with a peculiar [not quite] solution. This problem is that certain polygons aren't rendered unless I run 'fraps'. Needless to say, I would much rather my program to run without 3rd party programs. So I was wondering what part of my directx 11 code would be the cause of this.

Thanks in advance, please ask for code fragments if they're needed!

Comment: Have you tried narrowing down the problem yourself. Does this occur with any directx11 program or only your own. Have you updated your drivers?

Comment: It's purely this program. It's basically a recreated version of a win32 file I made and that ran fine. Having said that, I'll check how things are updated.

Comment: No luck with the updating.

Comment: Turns out I missed the depth values in the viewport setup.